# Factorizing $z^2-z\frac{a^2 +b^2}{ab}+1 = (z-a/b)(z-b/a)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The intermediate factorization calculation $z^2-z\frac{a^2 +b^2}{ab}+1 = (z-a/b)(z-b/a)$ was coined *straightforward* by Riley's Mathematical Methods for Physics and Engeneering (eq.24.66).

I've tried completing the square,

$$
z^2-z\frac{a^2 +b^2}{ab}+1 = 0 \\
 \bigg( z-\frac{a^2 +b^2}{2ab} \bigg)^2 +1 -\frac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{(2ab)^2} = 0 \\
\bigg( z-\frac{a^2 +b^2}{2ab} \bigg)^2 = \frac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{(2ab)^2}-1  \\
z= \frac{a^2 +b^2}{2ab}  \pm \sqrt{\frac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{(2ab)^2}-1} \ ,  \\
$$
which doesn't nearly suggest the simple end result.

I'm sure it will roll out after reorganizing terms, but I'm interested in an alternative approach which more naturally suggests the end result of $(z-a/b)(z-b/a)$, reflecting the word-use of *straightforward* in the text.

**Context.**

Using contour integration to evaluate $I = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\cos(2\theta)}{a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(\theta)}d\theta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab}=\frac ab+\frac ba$$
and
$$\frac ab\cdot\frac ba=1$$
Remember that, in a polynomial of second degree, the coefficient of $z$ is the opposite of sum of the roots and the costant term is their product.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, one can see that

$$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{a} = \frac{a^2 + b^2}{ab}$$

Going from the RHS to the LHS is called fraction decomposition.

Your result should be clearer now:

$$z^2 - z\left(\frac{a^2 + b^2}{ab}\right) + 1 = z^2 - z\frac{a}{b} - z\frac{b}{a} + 1 = \left(z - \frac{a}{b}\right)\left(z - \frac{b}{a}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

You have one mistake.

$\frac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{(ab)^2}$ this term should be

$\frac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{(2ab)^2}$ then its easily solve.

Comment: I've made the correction, thank you.

Comment: Your welcome. Now you get result. Or wants me to solve it further?

Comment: I got the gist, but thanks.

Answer (score -1):

it must be $$z_{1,2}=\frac{a^2+b^2}{2ab}\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{a^2+b^2}{2ab}\right)^2-1}$$
and we can factorize to $$-\frac{(a-bz)(az-b)}{ab}$$ and $$ab\ne 0$$

Comment: Shouldn't there be a factor two in the denominator of the first term?

Comment: yes thanks a lot, it is corrected

Comment: Made the correction, thanks.

Comment: Factorize after completing the square first is not my preferred approach in this case.